# Can worth be used in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I want to say that electronic news media proved better than traditional newspapers. Does the following sentence mean that?

> Electronic news media has proved its worth over the traditional
> published newspapers.

Comment: That sentence makes sense to me, and means what you want it to mean.

Comment: Many would say "Electronic news media **have** proved **their** worth over the **traditionally** published newspapers".

Comment: Yes @michael but many would not, and I have several data to evidence it.#